# Число и "& 0x7fffffff

Tags: c#

Видел много это `int num = (-23) & 0x7fffffff` но там и не нашел этому объяснения, так что это значит? Я слышал что убирает знак, но какой знак если не выходе максимальное число `(int32) - 23`

Comment: Если под "видел много это" вы подразумеваете декомпилированный код, то скорее всего имеется ввиду модуль от числа, т.к. псевдо код не строится на привычных функциях языков программирования. Обычно используются примитивы, близкие по смыслу к компиляции.

Comment: нижу можно увидеть сообщения от free_ze: "эта операция - не эквивалент взятию модуля числа"

Answer (score 5):

Как правило старший бит - знаковый (если он 1 - число отрицательное, 0 - положительное). С помощью маски (0x7fffffff) и коньюнкции старший бит сбрасывается в ноль, вне зависимости от его значения в исходном числе.

Но из-за того, что отрицательные числа записываются в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) (*знаковый бит - 1, а значение числа инвертировано, где обычно ноль - там единица и наоборот*), эта операция - не эквивалент взятию модуля числа.

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00010111‬ = 23 (DEC)
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111‬ = 0x7fffffff (HEX)
&
00000000 00000000 00000000 00010111 = 23 (DEC)
```

Но при этом:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11101001 = -23 (DEC)
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111‬ = 0x7fffffff (HEX)
&
01111111 11111111 11111111 11101001 = ‭2147483625‬ (DEC)
```

Comment: но как тогда отбросить знак? И почему мне в ответ на это дали: "Отбросить знак"? Если работать все равно не будет, и тогда зачем это использовать?

Comment: @k0vpack, вот уж не смогу предположить, зачем они вам так сказали) Для этого есть стандартная статическая функция `Math.Abs(Int32)`

Comment: предпочитаю использовать num < 0 ? num * -1 : num, обращения к функции из другого класса занимает куда больше времени, и в очень редких случаях (где нужно быстро обрабатывать)  мне кажется мой вариант будет лучшим

Comment: @k0vpack, это статический метод, компилятор его точно так же заинлайнит, при этом перед глазами вместо тернанрной глязи будет милая мнемоника. А внутри он [делает то же самое](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,1c02e346de90ef5a).

Comment: @k0vpack, если Вас волнует такая «оптимизация», зачем Вы вообще на C# пишете?

Comment: @ixSci игры под Unity пишу, но вдруг поинтересовался

Comment: @k0vpack, дам Вам совет тогда: забудьте про оптимизацию до того времени, пока не начнёте понимать, что и как нужно оптимизировать. Потому что сейчас у Вас совершенно неверные представления.

Comment: @ixSci так можете направить куда нужно?

Comment: @k0vpack, с опытом придёт. А пока читайте статьи и книги. Конкретно по C# мне известны только 2: «Writing high-performance .NET code» и «Effective C#». Хотя сам я их не читал. Большего всего это приходит с опытом, конечно. Ну и статьи разные тоже хорошо помогают.